# Django admin style application for Java

Tags: java, python, django

I'm looking for a web framework or an application in Java that does what Django admin does - provides a friendly user interface for editing data in a relational database. I know it's possible to run Django on Jython and that way achieve a somewhat Java-based solution, but I'd prefer something pure-Java to keep the higher-ups happy.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Grails](http://grails.org/). It's a framework modeled after Django, written in [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/). Groovy is a JVM based language, source-compatible with Java.

To get a Django-like admin interface, you write your models, let Grails generate all the rest (controllers and views), and you're done.

Some resources:

- [Quick Start Tutorial](http://grails.org/Quick+Start)
- [Screencast showing Scaffolding](http://mediap1.roadkast.com/hansamann/grails_scaffolding.mov)

Answer (score 4):

[Spring ROO](http://www.springsource.org/roo) is probably what you are looking for - it's a pure Java solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean is CRUD generating (CRUD: create, read, update, delete = typical admin interface). For example [Rife](http://rifers.org/theater/demo1_rifecrud) can do this.