# "Django Admin" like framework/app in Java

Tags: java, tomcat, h2

I'm looking for something like "Django Admin", i.e. that will enable quick table based editing in Java and embedded DB (H2 ??)

All ieads are welcomed

Ilan

Comment: Look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706405/django-admin-style-application-for-java

Answer (score 1):

You can try use grails with scaffolding plugin ;-)